# Crystal Reports - Moved to Win 10, reports work for coworker but not myself

Tags: crystal-reports

I've been searching your questions for a while, finding the answers to many of my own. But I can't find any help with these:

1-We recently migrated to Windows 10, and following that there are a few reports that work just fine for my coworker but not me. Most of our reports work fine either way. So far as we can tell, we have the same setup, same drivers, same ODBC connections, same versions, everything. Only I get no data, and he gets data. I don't get any error messages, just the report returns with all 0s when we know there is data to find.

2-Also, we have reports that pull from Outlook folders which also no longer work. We are getting a "non-numeric string" error for a field that returns a date and did not throw any errors before the migration. We are only able to return data from before the migration. When running those reports from a Windows 7 machine, we get the same issues plus a MAPI error pop up.

For the affected reports, I have re-built them from scratch on the Win 10 machine to no avail. We are scratching our heads about this, and think it has to be something on the backend that we don't have access to, but not sure what to bring up to the Sys Admin for resolution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Formula with non-numeric string error (formula previously worked without issue):

```
whileprintingrecords;

shared stringvar Monthpart;
shared numbervar Monthnum;
shared stringvar daypart;
shared numbervar daynum;
shared stringvar Yearpart;
shared numbervar yearnum;
shared numbervar hournum;
shared stringvar hourpart;
shared numbervar minpart;
shared numbervar IdPmAm;
shared datetimevar date2;

//Parse out data
Monthpart := {@Date}[1 to 2];
daypart := ToText({@Date}[4 to 5]);
Yearpart := ToText({@Date}[7 to 10]);
If (Instr({@Date},":")-Instr({@Date}," ")) = 3 then
(hournum := tonumber({@Date}[12 to 13]);
Minpart := tonumber({@Date}[(Instr({@Date},":")+1) to                                       (Instr({@Date},":")+2)]))
else if (Instr({@Date},":")-Instr({@Date}," ")) = 2 then
(hournum := tonumber({@Date}[12]);
Minpart :=  Tonumber({@Date}[(Instr({@Date},":")+1) to (Instr({@Date},":")+2)]))
else if (Instr({@Date},":")-Instr({@Date}," ")) = 0 then
(hournum := 0;
Minpart := 0;);
IdPmAm :=(Instr({@Date}, ":")+ 4);
If ({@Date}[IdPmAm]  = "P" and hournum <> 12) then
hournum := hournum + 12;
//Change data to numbers
If NumericText(MonthPart) then Monthnum := tonumber(Monthpart);
If NumericText(DayPart) then Daynum := tonumber(Daypart);
If NumericText(YearPart) then yearnum := tonumber(Yearpart);

Date2 := datetimevalue(Yearnum, Monthnum, Daynum, hournum, minpart, 00)
```

Comment: are you able to see the query generated by the crystal reports? Also can you post what is the formula that is returning the `non numeric string` error I guess you are trying to convert to number from a string

Comment: Yes, we can see & modify the query. The formula giving the error is this:

Comment: Error must be in these statements which has `tonumber({@Date}[12 to 13])` remove tonumber and then run the reports

Comment: My question here query generated by report when run on the database producing any results? also if you are able to see the data then check ODBC connection pointing to correct database.

Comment: How can I remove tonumber from the query & run the report? It's taking data mined from another field and converting it to a number. As for seeing the data in the database, one is Outlook and we can see the emails in the folder. The other report works for a coworker but not myself. The report itself has not been changed.

Comment: I am not asking to change the query but change the formula that you have pasted in question. When you are trying to convert a string to number this kind of errors occurs

Comment: As an update, I have figured out a solution for the 1st report I mentioned. I was taught to select "use underscores" when setting up the ODBC connection. I un-checked that and the report now runs fine for me.

Comment: When removing the "to number" formula, the report runs fine but we are unable to calculate time elapsed because it is pulling a time field. Is there anything that could have been changed during / after the migration to Win 10? I ask because we have no issues with data prior to that date, even on the Win 10 machines. But after that date we get all sorts of hiccups. I know that I need to follow-up with our admin with this, but he's not in the office for a few days & I am looking to get ideas for him to pursue when he returns.